# referencing elements of a user defined type column in a where clause

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I've got a table which has columns of user defined types:

```
create type my_udt as (
   x varchar(10),
   y numeric(5,3),
   z varchar(10)
);

create table udt_tab (
   a varchar(10),
   udt_col my_udt
);
```

then what I want to do is query it like:

```
select * from udt_tab t
where t.udt_col.x = 'Foo';
```

which would work fine in Oracle, but in Postgres it gives me:

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"
Position: 36

I've tried a few variations such as

```
select * from udt_tab
where udt_col_tab.udt_col.x = 'Foo';

select * from udt_tab t
where t.udt_col.x = 'Foo';
```

but nothing seems to work and I can't find anything in the manual about this.

We are migrating an existing Oracle database with lots of application code, so restructuring the table to avoid using the UDTs would add a lot of extra effort.

Comment: You created udt_tab and are referencing udt_col_tab; is that a typo?

Comment: yes, fixed now thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING) explains how to access attributes of composite types:

> You must write it like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT (item).name FROM on_hand WHERE (item).price > 9.99;
> ```
>
> or if you need to use the table name as well (for instance in a multitable query), like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT (on_hand.item).name FROM on_hand WHERE (on_hand.item).price > 9.99;
> ```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=40dad21c550775e4946ff330ad537cb6)

Comment: It's also documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was probably not entering the right search phrases to have found it.  It seems an odd syntax, but I'm sure I'll get used to it :)